# What is output caching, is it always good to use output caching to improve web app's performance?

Tags: asp.net, caching

What is output caching for a web application, is it always good to use output caching to improve web app's performance. Besides output caching, are there some other caching techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output caching stores a rendered page/control and spits back the stored HTML instead of having to generate it again for each request. Typically you do output caching for a specified period of time, for example 60 seconds.

On the first request, the output is cached, subsequent requests for the 60 second duration use the cached page instead of generating the html again. If this control is database intensive, then all subsequent requests for the 60 second duration saved database calls, etc, and the page load for the subsequent requests should be much faster.

Information on Output Caching is readily available on google.

Other caching techniques would include, but is definitely not limited to:

- [Browser Caching](http://merbist.com/2011/07/11/first-step-in-scaling-a-web-site-http-caching/)
- [Object Caching](http://memcached.org/about)
- [Query Caching](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx